# JPA - OneToMany struggle

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity `Property` which has several `PropertyAttributes` - managed as list, i.e.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinFetch(value = JoinFetchType.INNER)
private List<PropertyAttribute> propertyAttribute;
```

in the `PropertyAttribute` I have as well a reference to the `Property`, i.e.

```
@Id
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
@ManyToOne
private Property property;
```

when I save a new `Property`,e.g. `id=10400` than the additional `PropertyAttribute` is saved as well with the same id - as expected. My `save()`  method looks like:

```
public void save(){
   //begin transaction
   getEntityManager.persist(newProperty);
   // end transaction...
   //begin transaction...
   getEntityManager.merge(newPropertyAttriubtes);
   // end transaction
}
```

But when I perform the second round of `save()` (now with `id=10401`  then I get strange results, namely:

```
getEntityManager().find(Property.class,10400)
```

has now `PropertyAttribute` with `Property` - `id` = 10401, i.e. from the last saved record (=wrong content!)

Any ideas why it fails with the second save? Might it be a DB-issue? Or EclipseLink?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If the foreign key 'property_id' is the ID, how can this relationship be used in a OneToMany?  OneToMany implies there are many propertyAttributes with the very same ID value, making it not unique.  An ID should immutable: if a field used is something that needs to change, it should not be used as an ID.  Also make sure that you aren't just changing values on something you've already passed in to JPA to manage.

Comment: thx for the hint, i.e. last sentence - which lead to the proper track :-) Saved my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it properly :-/ Just in case others struggle the same...

```
public void save(){
   //begin transaction
   getEntityManager.persist(newProperty);
   // end transaction...
   newPropertyAttriubtes.forEach(attr -> {
          //begin transaction...
          getEntityManager.merge(attr);
          // end transaction
          newProperty.attach(attr)
   }
   //begin transaction
   // to have the PropertyAttributes attached in the EntityManager => merge
   getEntityManager.merge(newProperty); 
   // end transaction...
   }
}
```

Thx for Chris to point me to the correct direction to not change the Entity after JPA manage it!